# OpenGL - problem in rotating - Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl, logic

I am trying to learn||Code openGL in Qt. I made one application which shows two figures. One is a triangle "A", and the other triangle "B" is just the same as "A" except it got rotated -90 degree about the z-Axis(z axis is perpendicular to the computer screen). Now, the problem is rotation makes the change in the dimension. I am posting the "main.cpp" below,

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <QWidget>

class MyOpenGL:public QGLWidget
{
public:
    MyOpenGL(QWidget * parent);
    ~MyOpenGL();
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();
};

MyOpenGL::MyOpenGL(QWidget *parent):QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers),parent)
{
    setAutoFillBackground(false);
}

MyOpenGL::~MyOpenGL()
{

}

void MyOpenGL::initializeGL()
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
}

void MyOpenGL::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0f,width()/height(),10.0f,100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void MyOpenGL::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,4.0f,-10.0f);
    glEnd();

    glRotatef(90.0,0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,4.0f,-10.0f);
    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    MyOpenGL * f = new MyOpenGL(NULL);
    f->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is  the pro file

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

QT += opengl
```

This is the resulting app's screen shot

[image]

As for as I know rotation won't do any change in dimension. But here the dimension is changing .If anybody clear my doubt in this issue, I will be very thankful to him/her.

Comment: @VJo I edited the question. Read the last few lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say for certain what is going on, but I do see that there may be some problems.

```
gluPerspective(45.0f,width()/height(),10.0f,100.0f);
```

If `width` and `height` both return integers (and they probably do), then dividing one by the other will result in an integer. That's not going to give you a proper aspect ratio. Cast one of them to a float to get a real aspect ratio.

Next, try putting a glLoadIdentity() call at the top of the paintGL function.

Comment: I never thought about this. As you said width/height made all the mess. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a 2D rendering, use gluOrtho2D instead of gluPerspective (3D rendering).

Actually, it's not a problem, this is just normal projection of a 3D object onto 2D plane.

Comment: @Optillect After your suggestion I used gluOrtho2D(-10.0f,10.0f,-10.0f,10.0f). But I couldn't see any thing in the screen, it went blank.

Comment: No, that's not normal for projecting a 3D object. Not with a Z-rotation that he's doing. Objects under a perspective projection do not behave like that.

Comment: Of course, you must edit your code. 1) Try glVertex2d, 2) [some tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537007(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Nicol, that's normal projection. Look closer to the vertices (their coords).

Comment: @Optillect Team: What about his vertices? They have a Z of -10, so that they will be in view of the camera and not clipped by the near-clip. A rotation about the Z axis will not change their Z values, so they will not be getting closer or farther from the camera. What's the problem?

Comment: @Nicol, the base of the triangle is 2 units length, and the height of the triangle is 4 units. I mean, these two triangles won't look the same afer rotation, because of 3D projection.

Comment: Anyway, you are right about division of two integers. I've just noticed that the result depends on the matrix of perspective projection.

Comment: @Optillect Team: Perspective projection doesn't matter if the triangle is in the Z plane in camera space. It will not change the shape of the triangles like this. Perspective projection only changes the position of points if the Z positions of them are different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the view:

```
void MyOpenGL::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    gluPerspective(45.0f,(double)w/(double)h,10.0f,100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    updateGL();
}
```

Also, not need to reset the projection matrix when rendering the image :

```
void MyOpenGL::paintGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,4.0f,-10.0f);
    glEnd();

    glRotatef(90.0,0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,0.0f,-10.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f,4.0f,-10.0f);
    glEnd();
}
```

but as someone said, try to use glOrtho instead of gluPerspective

Comment: You still need the glLoadIdentity at the top (or the bottom, but the top is more explicit) to keep from accumulating successive rotations. `resizeGL` will only be called when the window changes size.

Comment: @Nicol Right, but the view has initially to be set in the initialization function.

Comment: @Nicol Right, completely forgot about it. fixed now

Answer (score -1):

In order to do a rotation, you have to first bring the thing to the origin and then rotate and then bring it bak to the place you want it.